# Clone remote git repository for local use without interfering with the remote branch

Tags: git

I want to clone the public Linux master branch from Kernel.org so I can experiment with the code on my personal computer without affecting the public branch. I have already performed `git clone` and a clone resides on my computer. How would I keep my experimenting from affecting the master branch?

Note: I'm using Windows.

Comment: Are you concerned about the `master` branch *in your clone*, or the one in the repository you cloned from? In the first case, just create a different branch to do your playing on. In the second, never run `git push ...` (you may not be able to anyway, due to permissions).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It doesn't matter if you use windows or any other operating system. If you have your local clone of a remote repository you can do whatever you want and as long as you don't use `git push origin master` the remote repository will not be affected. If you do not want to affect the local `master` branch then - just create another branch (`git checkout -b <branch_name>`) and work there.

I think [this book](http://git-scm.com/book/) is a nice read to get started with Git.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not entirely sure I understand what you want to avoid. If you have a clone, all work you do is only local to your clone. You are not able to break something in the remote repository (you don't have push permissions anyway).

The remote tracking branch `origin/master` will (after performing `git fetch`) always contain the current state of the official public repository.

Comment: I was going to experiment with the code without messing up the main Linux repository.

Comment: You are not able to mess up the main Linux repository. It would be really weird if everybody could do that, right?

Answer (score 0):

The best thing to do in your case is to fork the Linux master branch on github and then clone it. You can then play with your master branch and do whatever you want to do with it. 
In either case, nothing you do on your local master will affect the remote until you explicitly (try to) push to the remote, so not to worry. Also, you can always create another branch where you can try stuff - this is true with any project you want to work on.